# After upgrading my web app from .Net 3.5 to .Net4.0, I get a security transparency rules failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, instrumentation

After upgrading my web app from .Net 3.5 to .Net4.0, I get a security transparency rules failed.

[image]

I've never even heard of this or incorporated it into my project.
Does anyone have any idea what this may be?

Comment: image not shown ?? which is the error ?? Attempt to access method System.Management.Instrumentation.InstrumentedAttribute..ctor(System.String) in violation of security transparency rules failed. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft's knowledge-base [KB2635463](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2635463):

> **Cause**
>   This problem occurs because when the System.Web.UI.ScriptManager class
>   is first instantiated it builds a cache of method information for
>   classes in assemblies already loaded in the application. When it tries
>   to examine the constructor of the InstrumentedAttribute the exception
>   is thrown and not handled.
>
> **Resolution**
>   To workaround this issue reliably, instantiate an instance of
>   ScriptManager at a point during application start up prior to the
>   first request actually being executed but after the assembly that has
>   the InstrumentedAttribute has been loaded.
>
> For example, in global.asax add some new code to Application_Start:
>
> ```
> private void Application_Start(HttpApplication application) 
> { 
>     if (applicationStartupComplete) return; 
>     try 
>     { 
>         object osm = new System.Web.UI.ScriptManager(); 
>     } 
>     catch(Exception)
>     {}
> }
> ```

---

Additionally, a [post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1678578.aspx) at the asp.net forums reveals [this answer](http://forums.asp.net/post/4414840.aspx) from a Microsoft employee:

> We have seen a combination of issues that might cause this:
>
> > 1) The
> >     webserver has the trust level set less than "Full" at the machine
> >     web.config ([ref](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998341.aspx))
> >
> > 2) The webserver does not have the AJAX files (System.Web.Extensions)
> >     installed into the GAC.
>
> **Solution 1:** Set trust level to "Full" in the machine level web.config
>
> **Solution 2:** Install AJAX files into the GAC
>
> If refreshing resolves it - it might just be a timing issue loading
>   the extensions.  Probably if you install into the GAC it will resolve
>   it.

Comment: That solution is better than this workaround: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2635463 ??

Comment: @Kiquenet since my answer was from a Microsoft employee, I would go for Microsoft's official solution. I'll include it in my answer.

Comment: What is it applicationStartupComplete variable? any full source code using applicationStartupComplete ?